# Enironment Variable being rendered literal

Tags: assets, multi-environment, volumes

OK,
So created 2 variables in my local .env file

`ASSET_BASE_URL="https://mysite.local/resources"`

`ASSET_BASE_PATH="/Volumes/yada/yada/yada/resources"`

Then in the CP, created a new Asset volume and punched in

`Base URL = $ASSET_BASE_URL/gallery`

`File System Path = $ASSET_BASE_PATH/gallery`

Then front end renders an entries asset as:

`<img src="$ASSET_BASE_URL/_480x480_crop_center-center_80_none/doddle-01.jpg" alt="Doddle 01" width="480" height="480">`

THEN it creates a new folder named '$ASSET_BASE_PATH' at public site root.

I'm familiar with V2 it appears V3 has stepped up a bit. Could it be a Mamp issue with paths or somesuch trickery? Works if I hard code the paths as listed initially. All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't append anything to the value if you use environment variables. You need to use [aliases](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/#aliases) for this.

In you *config/general.php*, add this:

```php
'*' => [
    'aliases' => [
        'assetBasePath' => getenv('ASSET_BASE_PATH'),
        'assetBaseUrl' => getenv('ASSET_BASE_URL'),
    ],
],
```

Then in the asset volume settings, use the aliases in the **Base URL** & **File system path**:

[image]

Comment: Thx, updated as suggested but it still creates a folder at web root titled /public_html/@assetPath/sub_folders_etc

Answer (score 2):

For my future self, the aliases mention by nstCactus are required to reside within the `'*'` global setting area of general.php

```
'*' => [
    'defaultWeekStartDay' => 1,
    'cpTrigger' => 'admin',
    …
    'aliases' => [
    …
    …
    ]
]
```